# How to use the && macro variable in SAS

Tags: loops, sas, sas-macro

I'm working with SAS and I have to create some macro variables within a DO loop. This is a portion of my code:

```
%if &dsempty888=0 %then %do;
    data _null_;
    set freq_&&var&i;
        if &&var&i=888888888 then do;
            call symput("cont8_&&var&i",percent);
        end;
    run;
%end;
%if &dsempty888=1 %then %do;
    %let cont8_&&var&i=0;
%end;

%if &dsempty999=0 %then %do;
    data _null_;
    set freq_&&var&i;
        if &&var&i=999999999 then do;
            call symput("cont9_&&var&i",percent);
        end;
    run;
%end;
%if &dsempty999=1 %then %do;
    %let cont9_&&var&i=0;
%end;


%if &dsempty444=0 %then %do;
    data _null_;
    set freq_&&var&i;
        if &&var&i=444444444 then do;
            call symput("cont4_&&var&i",percent);
        end;
    run;
%end;
%if &dsempty444=1 %then %do;
    %let cont4_&&var&i=0;
%end;
```

This code is inside another DO loop that run from `i=1 to &end`.
With this my macro variables `cont4_&&var&i` `cont8_&&var&i` `cont9_&&var&i` are costantly overwrited...and they become unuseful outside of their loop. I tried to name them `&&cont4_&&var&i` for example. But clearly SAS doesn't solve the macro.
In practice inside of the loop the macro are created, but I don't know how to call them when I need outside.

How can I fix?

Thanks in advance.

Comment: Also see [this question](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/24895197/resolving-multiple-ampersands-with-macro-variables) and [this question](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/22903856/sas-macro-ampersand/22915555#22915555) for more information on multiple ampersand resolution.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

You've got a lot of issues here, so let's simplify this some.  Here's a very simplified example.  This, for example, does something:

```
%let var1 = age;
%let var2 = height;
%let var3 = weight;

proc freq data=sashelp.class noprint;
  tables age/out=freq_age;
  tables height/out=freq_height;
  tables weight/out=freq_weight;
run;


%macro get_freqs(var_count=);
  %do i = 1 %to &var_count.;
      data _null_;
        set freq_&&var&i;
        call symput("cont4_&&var&i",percent);
      run;
  %end;
%mend get_freqs;

%get_Freqs(var_count=3)
```

But now if we do

```
%put cont4_&&var&i;
```

Of course it doesn't work, since `&i` has no meaning.  So instead we replace that with, say, 1:

```
%put cont4_&&var1;
```

Now we get something.  But we don't get anything useful, do we, just the variable name.  But - at least that's something!

Now we don't really need the second `&` there, right?

```
%put cont4_&var1;
```

But we need a `&` before this to use the macro variable:

```
%put &cont4_&var1;
```

But now we get a warning message, `CONT4_ not resolved`.  Okay, let's add a second `&` to delay the resolution of the macro variable until `&var1` is resolved.

```
%put &cont4_&var1;
```

Well, that helped, now it says `CONT4_AGE not resolved`.  Why not?  We used `call symput` to define that, right?

The problem is *scoping*.  `call symput` probably scoped it locally, meaning it was defined in the macro but not outside of the macro.  For this we use `call symputx` and give it a global scope.

```
%macro get_freqs(var_count=);
  %do i = 1 %to &var_count.;
      data _null_;
        set freq_&&var&i;
        call symputx("cont4_&&var&i",percent,'g');
      run;
  %end;
%mend get_freqs;
```

This tells SAS that I want `&cont4_age` to be defined outside of the macro.  Otherwise it will only be available locally - inside the macro - and will get cleaned up.

Now, this works:

```
%put &&cont4_&var1;
```

But if you wanted to iterate over `&i` again, it's a *bit* more complex.  That's because you need to delay those ampersands multiple times, and allow several passes.

Here's what works:

```
%macro iterate_i(var_count=);
  %do i = 1 %to &var_count.;
    %put &&&&cont4_&&var&i.;
  %end;
%mend iterate_i;

%iterate_i(var_count=3);
```

Why do we need *four* `&`s?  Well, we need to get to `&&cont4_&var1`, right? That happens in the first pass.  Here are the three passes:

`&&&&cont4_&&var&i` -> `&&cont4_&var1` -> `&cont4_age` -> 5.26...

Each pass, the following happens:

- `&&` -> `&` (and save for next pass)
- `&` -> resolve macro variable

So, that's how you'd iterate over those.  You can of course explicitly specify at any level the macro variable - so all of these work:

```
%let i=1;
%put &&&&cont4_&&var&i;
%put &&cont4_&var1;
%put &cont4_age;
```