# SAS not resolving &MacroVar

Tags: sas, sas-macro

I have the following code:

```
option nomprint;
%let firstCurveLength = 50;
%let macroVar=first;
%put &&macroVar.CurveLength;
```

The last statement printed to the log is:

> &firstCurveLength

I don't understand why &firstCurveLength isn't resolved though, since it is a macro variable. I tested this with:

```
%put &firstCurveLength;
```

Log:

> 50

### Edit

For anyone landing here from a search engine, Joe [gave a great answer](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/22903856/sas-macro-ampersand/22915555#22915555) to this issue.

Comment: Add another & to your %put statement: %put &&&macroVar.CurveLength;

Comment: %put &&&macroVar.CurveLength; is printing to my log "&&&macroVar.CurveLength" - still not resolving.

Comment: Post your full log please. It works for me.

Comment: After closing out sas and re-running I now get the correct resolution for &&&macroVar.CurveLength. Thanks a lot.

Comment: Search communities.sas.com as well, good community

Comment: Also relevant - [this question](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/22903856/sas-macro-ampersand/22915555#22915555) with more detail.